Double relative clauses and missing particles
Call You... Kimi to Boku no Mirai and Ignition! have a lot of verses that are either relative clauses or inverted clauses that require moving things around. It's hard to tell which are what, especially with so many missing particles.
From Call You...

どんな敵  来ても  僕たちの  本気(パワー)
イグニッション  火を付けた  勇気

イグニッション seems to be on its own, so translate the lyric as if the word isn't there?



この空の  蒼を  大いなる  黒が
呑み込んでく  切れそうな  鼓動

I don't understand the を before 大いなる黒. Does a verb after one in the でいく form result in an 'and' or comma? i.e., A great blackness is engulfing the blue in this sky, an expiring heartbeat (heartbeat about to expire/give out)/a pulse about to give out.



今  僕は誓う  取り戻せ  未来

I doubt two を's make sense here, so how would this work? 取り戻せ seems to be in the imperative form, so putting 誓う after it would be weird.


From Ignition!

君の中で目覚めた希望
弾け飛んだ空の彼方へ

How to interpret 彼方 (kanata)?



僕らの明日乗せたメロディー

Our future is resting on that melody or The melody that carried our future?



蹴散らせよ創造の
この星を護るため

Does the の on the first line replace が or を?



傷ついたこの空を
今だから抱きしめる

How does だから work here? Is it だから or 今だから, which is interpreted as 今?


